# Add index of value_counts() to new column for each group in groupby

Tags: python, pandas

There have been some variations of this question already but I can't find the exact thing I'm looking for.

I have a customer dataframe with the products they've purchased:

```
   customer product
0      John    Milk
1      John    Milk
2      John  Shoes 
3      John  Shoes 
4      John  Shoes 
5      John   Bread
6      Mary    Milk
7      Mary    Milk
8      Mary    Milk
9      Mary    Milk
10     Mary    Milk
11     Mary    Milk
12     Mary  Shoes 
13     Mary  Shoes 
14      Joe   Bread
15      Joe   Bread
16      Joe   Bread
17      Joe   Bread
18      Joe    Milk
19      Joe    Milk
20      Joe    Milk
21      Joe   Fruit
22      Joe   Fruit
23      Joe  Shoes 
24      Joe  Shoes 
25      Joe  Shoes 
26      Joe    Beer
27      Joe    Beer
28      Joe    Beer
29      Joe    Beer
```

Note: In the full dataframe the customers have hundreds of products so it can't just be a simple join / set of products in the column.

I would like get the top 5 products ( `value_counts()` ) for each customer and have the product names in a separate column. Not the count of the products, just the product names (the index of the value couts), and in the correct order of the value counts.

My goal is to have a dataframe like this:

```
  customer                        Top 5
0     John             Shoes Milk Bread
1     Mary                   Milk Shoes
2      Joe  Bread Beer Milk Shoes Fruit
```

I think I am on the right track with this line, I can see each customers Top 5 products:

```
newdf.groupby('customer')['product'].value_counts()

customer  product
Joe       Beer       4
          Bread      4
          Milk       3
          Shoes      3
          Fruit      2
John      Shoes      3
          Milk       2
          Bread      1
Mary      Milk       6
          Shoes      2
```

I am just not able to extract the information from this dataframe in the format I like. I have tried resetting the index and slicing etc. but I can't seem to get it right.

Comment: Why not iterate through groups directly? groupby customer and product, sort it, and iterate through the first five groups

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Series.value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html) in lambda function for join top 5 values of index with [`GroupBy.agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.agg.html):

```
f = lambda x: ' '.join(x.value_counts().index[:5])
df = (newdf.groupby('customer')['product'].agg(f)
           .reset_index(name='Top 5'))
print (df)  
 customer                         Top 5
0      Joe  Bread Beer Shoes Milk Fruit
1     John             Shoes Milk Bread
2     Mary                   Milk Shoes
```

If ordering of customer is important:

```
f = lambda x: ' '.join(x.value_counts().index[:5])
df = (newdf.groupby('customer', sort=False)['product'].agg(f)
           .reset_index(name='Top 5'))
print (df)  
  customer                        Top 5
0     John             Shoes Milk Bread
1     Mary                   Milk Shoes
2      Joe  Bread Beer Shoes Milk Fruit
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. But I need the top 5 only. I tried with `value_counts().head(5)` but it isn't working. I know in my sample there are not a lot of products, but pretend there are 100s of products. I also tried `nlargest(5)` after your `value_counts`.

Comment: @SCool - I try simplify answer, now it is for top5

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
fn = lambda _: _.value_counts().index.to_list()
df.groupby('customer')['product'].apply(fn).reset_index()
```

If you want `Top 5` as a string instead of a set:

```
outdf['Top 5'] = outdf['product'].str.join(', ')
```

Comment: This is not in the order of the value counts. You can see for example, John's top products in order are shoes milk and bread. Your method is Bread Shoes Milk.

Comment: Gotcha, amended.

Answer (score 2):

```
from collections import Counter


def fn(s):
    return ", ".join(k for k, v in Counter(s).most_common(5))

df.groupby("customer")["product"].apply(fn)
```

```
customer
Joe     Bread, Beer, Milk, Shoes, Fruit
John                 Shoes, Milk, Bread
Mary                        Milk, Shoes
Name: product, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 2):

Chain the function together

```
s=df.groupby(['customer','product']).size().sort_values(ascending=Fasle).\
     groupby(level=0).head(5).reset_index().\
     groupby('customer').product.agg(','.join)
customer
Joe     Bread,Beer,Shoes,Milk,Fruit
John               Shoes,Milk,Bread
Mary                     Milk,Shoes
Name: product, dtype: object
```